# How to style paper elements inside of a custom element (Polymer 1.0)?

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Whatever I do, I can't seem to be able to style paper-elements using custom properties inside a custom element:

```
<dom-module id="ts-dashboard">
  <style>
      :host {
         display: block;
          --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color : #ED1C23;
      }
      paper-tabs {
         background-color : #962E33;
      }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
        <paper-tab>Choice 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Choice 2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <!-- some more elements... -->
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
   //Module definition here
</script>
```

But the `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color` is not taken into account, and I end up with the default yellow instead of bright red.

Notably, I use shadow-dom instead of shady-dom, but switching back to the shady implementation hasn't changed anything. I also use a theme file, as an html import, to set `--default-primary-color` and other custom properties of the sort. These seem to work though, inside the `:root{ }` css property, but even if I put `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color : #ED1C23;` there it doesn't work either.

I have tried with `paper-input-controller` but the styles don't get applied either. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do not use is="custom-style". That is to be used when using styling local DOM in the main document. To use inside another Polymer custom element, just use the normal style tags without any attribute.

Comment: maybe the yellow is a more specific styling, like paper-tabs[selected] paper-tab or something

Comment: @Aravind I actually put it there out of desperation ^^ but Thanks for the clarification

Comment: What's wrong with just adding the `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color` to  `paper-tabs` instead of `:host`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use import an external style sheet like:

```
<dom-module id="ts-dashboard">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="ts-dashboard.css">
  <template>
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
        <paper-tab>Choice 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Choice 2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <!-- some more elements... -->
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
   //Module definition here
</script>
```

Then this should work:

```
paper-tabs {
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: #ED1C23;
}
```

(Update: Just realized I pasted that wrong. Fixed to what is in my external CSS file)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll give it a try on monday and get back to you.

Comment: That did work. I can't change the ripple color now though. But that's a start. :)

Comment: Turns out the external import was not necessary. Inlining works alright. But I wonder what I did wrong the first time I tried.